# OnPagePropertiesChanging event not firing?

Tags: asp.net, datapager, data-paging

```
 <div class="listQuestions">
    <asp:ListView ID="lstQuestions" runat="server" 
        OnPagePropertiesChanging="lstQuestions_PagePropertiesChanging">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <div id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server">
                <div id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                </div>
            </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="questionInfo">
                <h2>
                    <%#Eval("Title") %>
                </h2>
                <div class="tags">
                    <%#Eval("Description") %>                        
                </div>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
    <div>
    <asp:DataPager ID="lvQuestionsPager" PagedControlID="lstQuestions" PageSize="3" runat="server">
         <Fields>
        <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonType="Link" />
    </Fields>
    </asp:DataPager>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using a listview to bind a list of questions.
And a data pager.
The Datapager pageproperties changing event is not fired after the first page.
And in the code behind I have

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindQuestionsListView();//Binding a list of questions.
        }

    }
protected void lstQuestions_PagePropertiesChanging(object sender, PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        lvQuestionsPager.SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, false);
        BindQuestionsListView();
    }
```

I am binding a list of questions in the bind list view().
This event is not getting fired what could be the issue with dis.

Comment: I'm running into the exact same issue. Did you resolve this problem?